# Approximating the average of a list consisting of real numbers

Tags: probability-theory, algorithms, variance, average

Given a list of real number $(a_1, a_2, \ldots,a_n)$ we are interested in the average $\mu = \dfrac{1}{n}\displaystyle\sum_{i = 1}^{n}a_n.$ You are given a simple probabilist algorithm that approximates $\mu:$

1. Choose a parameter $k$ (is a fixed parameter you determine and thus not choosen at random)
2. $s := 0$
3. repeat $k$ times:

   $i\leftarrow$ uniformly at random choosen index $1\leq i\leq n$

   $s \leftarrow s + a_i$
4. $X = \dfrac{s}{k}$
5. return $X$

I'm asked to show that $\text{Var}[X] \leq \dfrac{1}{4k}.$ So far I noticed that clearly $\mathbb{E}[X] = \mu$ and for estimating the variance one probably wants to make use of the formula $\text{Var}[X] = \mathbb{E}[X^2]-\mathbb{E}[X]$ but I don't know how to determine $X^2.$ Could someone give me an advice how to proceed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that $\forall i$, $a_i\in [0,1]$.

The algorithm can be analyzed by defining the i.i.d random variables $X_1,\ldots,X_k$ , each with uniform distribution over the set $\{a_1,\ldots,a_n\}$.

Then the output of the algorithm is $X=\frac 1k \sum_{i=1}^k X_i$ and $$\operatorname{Var}(X) = \frac 1k \operatorname{Var}(X_1)\leq \frac 1{4k}$$

where the last inequality follows from [Popoviciu's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Popoviciu%27s_inequality_on_variances).

Comment: thanks a lot! Doesn't your answer with the algorithm above also answer this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4123091/bit-strings-and-probability? Since you could basically apply the above algorithm and use Chebychev's inequality to determine the number of bits to choose.